# Unable to resolve error: list index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to run the same code in PHP but it is working fine where as when try to run it on Python it is giving me the following error:

```
if my_queue[int_neighbour]['visited'] == '0':
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Input:

```
1 0 A 2,3
2 0 B 1,4,5
3 0 C 1,2
4 0 D 2,5
5 0 E 2,4
```

Full Code:

```
import string
import time
start_time = time.time() #starting time
file_name = input('Enter a file name: ')
f = open(file_name, 'r')
data = f.readlines()
final_data = []

for line in data:
      values = line.split()
      neighbors = values[3].split(',')
      vertex_mod = int(values[0])-1
      read_line = dict({
                'vertex': vertex_mod,
                'visited': values[1],
                'letter': values[2],
                'neighbors': neighbors
                })
      final_data.append(read_line)


def dfs(vertex, my_queue):
    if vertex['visited'] == '0':
            print(vertex['letter'])
            int_vertex = int(vertex['vertex'])
            my_queue[int_vertex]['visited'] = '1';
            for neighbour in vertex['neighbors']:
                      int_neighbour = int(neighbour)
                      if my_queue[int_neighbour]['visited'] == '0':
                          result_queue = dfs(my_queue[int_neighbour], my_queue)


      return my_queue


dfs(final_data[1], final_data)
```

The output i am getting seems to be correct but i am also getting the error.

Comment: Why are you importing `string`? How is PHP relevant? I can assure you the "same code" won't work in PHP.

Comment: put in a couple of `print` as you traverse the structure and verify that it looks as expected. When you find the problem and you don't understand why, please update your question and we'll gladly help you. Good luck with the debugging

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one error. Your neighbors are 1-indexed and your list is 0-indexed. (This was also hard to debug; I suggest getting an editor that can indent consistently for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I really understand your code, but try to change this line

```
int_neighbour = int(neighbour)
```

into

```
int_neighbour = int(neighbour) -1
```

Your data-structure is:

```
{'neighbors': ['2', '3'], 'visited': '0', 'vertex': 0, 'letter': 'A'}
{'neighbors': ['1', '4', '5'], 'visited': '0', 'vertex': 1, 'letter': 'B'}
{'neighbors': ['1', '2'], 'visited': '0', 'vertex': 2, 'letter': 'C'}
{'neighbors': ['2', '5'], 'visited': '0', 'vertex': 3, 'letter': 'D'}
{'neighbors': ['2', '4'], 'visited': '0', 'vertex': 4, 'letter': 'E'}
```

and it looks like you use `int_neighbour` as an index into the array. The array is zero-indexed and your inputfile uses 1-5 as identifiers.